# How can Ether be withdrawn from a contract successfully using transfer?

Tags: solidity, ether, address.transfer, state-transition

New to Solidity...

I am studying how to **withdraw** Ether from a smart contract by setting a parameter in a function. Based on the value the function receives, an amount of Ether is sent to a contract wallet address. My goal is to use address.transfer(amount in wei) as discussed here...

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=.transfer

The issue is I am not able to execute the transfer of Ether from the contract address. I am using Remix in conjunction with a local blockchain, and I have confirmed that all my accounts are unlocked, so I should be able to send ether from this contract.

Below is the source that I am studying with...

The idea is that if a value of 1 - 3 is provided, then 24, 12, or 6 Ether is sent to the address held in variable remMem. I set x = y to verify that the value was received by the function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract ETHTEST {

    uint256 public y;
    address public remMem = 0x4152B21f407Ba23c6118c1641821EC4250DBf3B1;

    function transferETH(uint256 x) public payable returns(uint256){
    // y = x;
    // return;   

        if (x == 1){

            y = x;
            remMem.transfer(24000000000000000000);
            return;
        }

        if (x == 2){

            y = x;
            remMem.transfer(12000000000000000000);
            return;
        }

        if (x == 3){

            y = x;
            remMem.transfer(6000000000000000000);
            return;
        }

        if (x >=4 || x < 0){  //works
            revert();
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

How would I code the transfer of Ether successfully? Useful guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a payable function to accept Ether

```
function () public payable {
    // this function enables the contract to receive funds
}
```

It doesn't need to do anything, but you can add logic in there if you need some.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, it solved my understanding gap.